# Markov property on a special case of bernouli random walk

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, random-walk

my problem is that I have a two Bernoulli Random walks
\begin{align}
X(n) = X_0 + \sum_{k \in \lbrace 1,...,n \rbrace} X_k
\end{align}
with $X_0= (y_0,z_0) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $X_k = (Y_k, Z_k)$ whereby $Y_k, Z_k$ are both independently Bernoulli distributed.

In addition, for both random walks should hold: $Y_k > Z_k \forall k \in \lbrace 1,...,n \rbrace$.

I am looking for the transition probability:

\begin{align}
p(X_n, (i,j)) := \mathbb{P}(X_{n+1} = (i,j)| \sigma(X_0,...,X_n), Y_k > Z_k \forall k \in \lbrace 1,...,n +1 \rbrace )
\end{align}

for $i,j \in \lbrace -1,1 \rbrace$. 
It would as well help me to fix the notation for the line above, since mixing an σ-algebra and a set seems to be inappropriate for me.

Thanks for taking your time.